# Finding demographics for a model in R Lavaan

Tags: statistics, r-lavaan

I am currently in a pickle. I have taken a subsample from a sample (General Social Survey; GSS). The subsample has certain features that the rest of the data doesn't have.

Other features are: IV is a manifest variable; the 3 mediators are composite variables; The DV is a 5 item latent variable; my subsample has a 706 participants. The entire GSS has over 2,400 participants.

In my model I have several variables that work in concert with each other. Do the demographics have to be assessed in combination with all of the variables in play? So, I think I need to find demographics of the entire model in play? How would I find demographic information for this model?

Or is there a way to create a variable for the entire model? And then look for certain features such as socioeconomic status, age and gender.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking here.  What do you mean by the demographics of the entire model in play? How does this differ from the demographics of your sample?

Comment: It differs because the entire sample of the data is 2,348 participants. My model is a portion of the entire sample (706 participants). So, I am trying find the range and average for my portion of the data for these variables: Socioeconomic status and Age

Comment: Do you know who the 706 are? Why can't you look at the average for them?

Comment: That's my question, I am trying to figure who my 706 (subsample) are. Age and socioeconomic status are variables outside of my subsample model. My DV is the only latent variable in my model.  Is there an R code I can use to find how many participants in my subsample are 40 years old and have an income over $25,000?

Comment: How are you creating your subsample?